# Resource POST Acting as GET method angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying to learn angularjs, so today i tryed using resource.
looks like it all went good at syntax and method calling,

Please open the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yd37/13/) first

Initially i tried with $http POST, looks like it worked

```
$http({url: '/register.php', method: "POST",
data: { 'message' : {userName:'ravi'}}});
```

With PHP code:

```
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);
    ....
    ....
    //insert stmt to mysql
```

Next, When i tried with $resource, with

**In  registerController**

```
authProviders.saveUser($scope.newuser);
```

**In authProviders service :**

> ```
> return $resource(AppConstants.ServerPath + '/register.php/:registerId',
>             {registerId: '@registerId'},{
>                 saveUser: {
>                     method: 'POST',
>                     params: {   message: {userName:'ravi'} },
>                     isArray: false
>                 }
>             });
> ```

The call is going like get method. 
Can any Body of you please Correct me in these.

My question question :
When you fill the form and submit which is in fiddle, the URL in the console look like

http://fiddle.jshell.net/register.php?message=%7B%22userName%22:%22ravi%22%7D
Which looks like GET method, even through the method type is POST

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly is it that does not work?

Comment: I have given as method: 'POST', but if you open the fiddle and jsut to fill the form, on click of the button the Request is going as GET method.

Comment: Actually when I click the "register me" on your fiddle I see a POST request...

Answer (score 0):

Remove params from Resources:

```
 return $resource(AppConstants.ServerPath + '/register.php/:registerId',
        {registerId: '@registerId'},{
            saveUser: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {   message: {userName:'ravi'} }, //Remove This
                isArray: false
            }
        });
```

Comment: If i remove the params, then how to post the data ?

Comment: GOT the answer. it is simple

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the GET method, then you have to say

> method: **'GET'**,
>   **params**: {   message: {userName:'ravi'} },

If you want to make it as POST, then

> method: **'POST'**,
>   **data**: {   message: {userName:'ravi'} },